# How can do this PHP code using DRY method?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dry

I am trying find out Everyday's sale of present month from day 01 to 30th . i am using the date function again and again. and using the same variable everytime . my code is big and looks ridiculously bad . how can i make this code smarter so that i dont have to write all these code . all things can be done using only one loops.... thanks

```
    //first date
    $todaySdate=date("Y-m-01 " );
    $todayEdate=date("Y-m-01 23:59:59 ");
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('ospos_sales AS A');
    $this->db->join('ospos_sales_payments AS B', 'B.sale_id = A.sale_id', 'left');  
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time >=', $todaySdate);
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time <=', $todayEdate);
    $Todaysales = $this->db->get()->result_array();      

    $todaySale=0;
     foreach($Todaysales as $d)
     {
        $todaySale+=$d['payment_amount'];
     }

     echo $todaySdate.'TK  :' .number_format( $todaySale,"2" )."</br>";

     $startDate=date("Y-m-d" );
     $endDate=date("Y-m-d");


   // second date
     $todaySdate=date("Y-m-02 " );
    $todayEdate=date("Y-m-02 23:59:59");
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('ospos_sales AS A');
    $this->db->join('ospos_sales_payments AS B', 'B.sale_id = A.sale_id', 'left');  
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time >=', $todaySdate);
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time <=', $todayEdate);
    $Todaysales = $this->db->get()->result_array();      

    $todaySale=0;
     foreach($Todaysales as $d)
     {
        $todaySale+=$d['payment_amount'];
     }

     echo $todaySdate.'TK  :' .number_format( $todaySale,"2" )."</br>";

     $startDate=date("Y-m-d" );
     $endDate=date("Y-m-d");


     //third date
     $todaySdate=date("Y-m-03 " );
    $todayEdate=date("Y-m-03 23:59:59");
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('ospos_sales AS A');
    $this->db->join('ospos_sales_payments AS B', 'B.sale_id = A.sale_id', 'left');  
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time >=', $todaySdate);
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time <=', $todayEdate);
    $Todaysales = $this->db->get()->result_array();      

    $todaySale=0;
     foreach($Todaysales as $d)
     {
        $todaySale+=$d['payment_amount'];
     }

     echo $todaySdate.'TK  :' .number_format( $todaySale,"2" )."</br>";

     $startDate=date("Y-m-d" );
     $endDate=date("Y-m-d");

     // fourth date date
     $todaySdate=date("Y-m-04 " );
    $todayEdate=date("Y-m-04 23:59:59");
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('ospos_sales AS A');
    $this->db->join('ospos_sales_payments AS B', 'B.sale_id = A.sale_id', 'left');  
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time >=', $todaySdate);
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time <=', $todayEdate);
    $Todaysales = $this->db->get()->result_array();      

    $todaySale=0;
     foreach($Todaysales as $d)
     {
        $todaySale+=$d['payment_amount'];
     }

     echo $todaySdate.'TK  :' .number_format( $todaySale,"2" )."</br>";

     $startDate=date("Y-m-d" );
     $endDate=date("Y-m-d");

     // Fifth date
     $todaySdate=date("Y-m-05 " );
    $todayEdate=date("Y-m-05 23:59:59");
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('ospos_sales AS A');
    $this->db->join('ospos_sales_payments AS B', 'B.sale_id = A.sale_id', 'left');  
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time >=', $todaySdate);
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time <=', $todayEdate);
    $Todaysales = $this->db->get()->result_array();      

    $todaySale=0;
     foreach($Todaysales as $d)
     {
        $todaySale+=$d['payment_amount'];
     }

     echo $todaySdate.'TK  :' .number_format( $todaySale,"2" )."</br>";

     $startDate=date("Y-m-d" );
     $endDate=date("Y-m-d");
     ........
      .......
      .......
```

Sample Output of my code..

```
2017-09-01 TK :0.00
2017-09-02 TK :1,186.55
2017-09-03 TK :1,311.45
2017-09-04 TK :0.00
.........
........ .
2017-09-30 TK :0.00
```

Comment: You might find this question more suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: As noted, this would be better for code review, but I would start with making a function  or class/method to contain the dup code.

Comment: can you help me how ? @Rasclatt

Comment: You could also do this with a `for()` loop, just increment the `date()`

Answer (score 0):

Here example, how you can refactor your code.

```
<?php

function get_today_sales (\DateTime $date) {
    $start_date = $date->setTime(0, 0);
    $end_date = $start_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));

    /*    
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('ospos_sales AS A');
    $this->db->join('ospos_sales_payments AS B', 'B.sale_id = A.sale_id', 'left');  
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time >=', $todaySdate);
    $this->db->where('A.sale_time <=', $todayEdate);
    $Todaysales = $this->db->get()->result_array();      

    $todaySale = 0;
    foreach($Todaysales as $d) {
        $todaySale+=$d['payment_amount'];
    }

    return $today_sale;
    */
}

$start = new DateTime('2017-10-01');
$end = new DateTime('2017-10-20');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);


foreach ($period as $day) {
    printf("%s -> %s\n", $day->format('Y-m-d'), get_today_sales($day));
}
```

Comment: Of course. It is not working code. Just example for you, to see how you can rewrite your code

Comment: @MirthfulNahid at least remove comment block and change name of variables ;-)